# Can I use my UK Mac Mini (Mid 2010)  in the US?

Tags: mac-mini, power

I'm from England and I'll be going to the US and I'd like to take my Mac Mini (Mid 2010) ([not the newest version](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP585)).

My main question is: would it be safe to use over there?

I'm worried because of the voltage difference.

If so should I purchase a US power supply cable (does Apply even sell these separately) or a UK->US plug adapter?

Comment: The apple online store has online chat and toll free support here. They would be my first stop to see how much a US power cord would cost. It's smaller to pack even though you only need a plug adapter to safely plug yours in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is safe. You will need a US plug adapter or a replacement cord, but the mac itself is good to go.

Reading through the specs it states:

Electrical and operating requirements
Line voltage: 100-240V AC

The power supply can handle both the frequency and voltage changes.

And for the question about buying a power cable or use an adapter -> Up to you I did use both and didn't have any problems. I'd go for a US power cable since that is less clunky, if you stay for longer. If it's only for a few weeks I wouldn't bother buying a cable.